# Static schema method: Cannot read property 'myFindOrCreate' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose, babeljs, mean-stack

To operate on my mongoose-Schemas I like to create static methods, but I have to admit, that it the first time I tried to get the MEAN-stack-backend up and running. The front-end and express routing is working fine, so we concentrate on the **schemas** first:

```
// tracking.model.ts
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var TrackingModuleSchema = new Schema ({
    // internal _id
    modulename :  { type: String, required:true,unique:true },
});
TrackingModuleSchema.statics.myFindByName= function (name,cb) {
    return this.findOne( {name:new RegExp(name,'i')},cb);
};
TrackingModuleSchema.statics.myFindOrCreate = function (name,cb) {
    this.myFindByName(name,function(err,modules) {
        console.error(err);
        console.log(modules);
        cb(err,modules); // TODO return module._id....
    });
};

// Create a `schema` for the Tracking object
var TrackingSchema = new Schema({
    // _id internal.
    timestamp: {type: Date },
    sequence : { type: Number },
    module: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'TrackingModule'  },
    severity: { type: String},
    action: { type: String },
    from: { type: String },
    to: { type: String },
});
// removed some code (Static methods to TrackingSchema)...
// create schema objects
var TrackingModule = mongoose.model('TrackingModule',TrackingModuleSchema);
var Tracking = mongoose.model('Tracking',TrackingSchema);

// module.exports all objects...
module.exports = function ( ) {
      return { 
        TrackingModule : TrackingModule ,
        Tracking : Tracking,
        };
    }
```

Now the **routing**, in which the schemas are imported and used:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
import {Tracking,TrackingModule} from '../models/tracking.model';

router.get('/module', (req,res) => {
    var moduleName = '';
    if (req.query.moduleName) {
        moduleName = req.query.moduleName;
    } else {
        console.log('Empty tracking-moduleName');
        res.send(500);
        return;
    }
    // the error happens in the following line:
    TrackingModule.myFindOrCreate(moduleName,function(err,msgId){
        if (err) {
            console.error(err); // errors with tracking ->console...
            res.send(500);
        } else {
            res.json( msgList );
        }
    });
});
// removed code for other gets and posts, not releveant to the error.

module.exports = router;
```

The error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'myFindOrCreate' of undefined` is occuring even when I try to rename the name of the static function. and Yes, I'm not finished with the implementation of myFindOrCreate.
Before that the import was not recognized, so I have installed babel-cli 6.23.0 following [this instruction](https://github.com/babel/example-node-server). I'm using the starts-skript from my **package.json**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "starts": "nodemon server/server.js --watch server --exec babel-node",
    "builds": "babel lib -d server.dist",
    "serve": "node server.dist/server.js",
    "tests": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register"
  },
```

However, the builds,serve and tests I didn't manage to work either, I will check that later. Right now I've checked all "Similar Questions" on right hand side of the question editor as well all of "Questions that may already have your answer" above this editor, nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `tracking.model.ts` file, instead of this:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return {
    TrackingModule: TrackingModule,
    Tracking: Tracking,
  };
}
```

Use `export` keyword, like this:

```
export const TrackingModule = TrackingModule;
export const Tracking = Tracking;
```

You cannot mix-up the older `module.exports` pattern with the ES6 `export-import` pattern. They are processed differently.

Comment: I have to change already the `var TrackingModule =` to the `export const TrackingModule = mongoose.model...`. Thanks for the essential hint into the right direction.